# Excel inventario Error 1004: Error definido por la aplicación o el objeto

Tags: excel, macros

Tengo un control de inventario y llego un momento que en el apartado de "salida de material me lanza el error 1004" ustedes me podrían ayudar por favor para saber cual es generador del error

PRIMERA PARTE

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SEGUNDA PARTE

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

TERCERA PARTE

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CUARTA PARTE LA DEL ERROR

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

código

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()



Dim i As Integer
Dim final As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim actual As Double

For i = 1 To 1000
If Hoja3.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
final = i
Exit For
End If
Next

Hoja3.Cells(final, 1) = UserForm3.ComboBox1
Hoja3.Cells(final, 2) = UserForm3.TextBox1
Hoja3.Cells(final, 3) = UserForm3.TextBox3
Hoja3.Cells(final, 4) = UserForm3.TextBox5
Hoja3.Cells(final, 5) = UserForm3.TextBox6
Hoja3.Cells(final, 6) = UserForm3.TextBox7

For j = 1 To 1000
If Hoja6.Cells(j, 1) = Hoja3.Cells(final, 1) Then
actual = Hoja6.Cells(j, 3)
final = actual - UserForm3.TextBox3
Hoja6.Cells(j, 3) = final
Exit For
End If
Next

UserForm3.ComboBox1 = ""
UserForm3.TextBox1 = ""
UserForm3.TextBox2 = ""
UserForm3.TextBox3 = 0
UserForm3.TextBox4 = ""
UserForm3.TextBox5 = ""
UserForm3.TextBox6 = ""
UserForm3.TextBox7 = ""


UserForm21.Hide
UserForm3.Hide

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

UserForm21.Hide

End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Qué línea da el error? ¿Qué valores tienen las variables en el momento del error? ¿Has probado a debuguearlo paso a paso con F8?

Comment: Revisa como dice Esei la ejecución del programa. Entiendo que no estas muy habituado a hacerlo. Solo tienes que establecer un punto de interrupción justo a la derecha de una linea de codigo, por ejemplo en el if hoja3... Para hacerlo da click justo a la derecha de la linea que quieres que se detenga cuando la ejecucion llegue a ese punto. Veras un circulo de color junto a la linea y que funciona porque al ejecutar la salida de material excel te muestra la linea y se detiene. Después con f8 puedes ir avanzado linea a linea para ver que linea genera el error.

Comment: Pero antes de nada, comentarte que el "for 1 to 1000" para saber que linea esta vacia es algo imperfecto. Mejor:
final = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
y esa linea sustituiria a todo el for...
Por otro lado, cuando declaras la variable final , es mejor que esta sea de tipo Long ( Dim final as Long) porque Integer solo admite hasta 32767 valores, por lo que si la linea es superior tendras problemas de desbodamiento.
Para finalizar, revisa que los nombres de las cajas sea mas descriptivos, así evitas posibles errores (que puede ser el caso de tu error) en Diseño- Propiedades

Comment: Compañero ando intentando, te agradezco mucho por haberte tomando el tiempo de ayudarme.

Comment: y el error lo lanza es donde esta resaltado en amarillo este es mi correo carlosandresc679@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

### Sugerencias

Primero recomiendo que uses nombres descriptivos para las variables, en este caso ponerle nombres internos a las hojas es buena idea, ejemplo `wsSalidas`, `wsEntradas`, etc, el prefijo ws es para saber que se trata de una hoja de calculo (`WorkSheet`).
Esto se hace desde el mismo editor, a la izquierda seleccionas el objeto de la hoja correspondiente y cambias la propiedad (`Name`) por un nombre descriptivo que inicie con un prefijo como "`ws`".

Trabajar con esos nombres `Hoja1`, `Hoja2`, etc, es un autentico dolor.

Esto ayuda porque al estar escribiendo código, si escribes `ws` y presionas `Control tab`, se desplegaran todos los nombres que inicien con eso, por lo cual es muy posible que todos los nombres de hojas de calculo que has definido se mostraran primero y podrás seleccionar el necesario de forma sencilla.

Hacer lo mismo con los formularios y nombres de campos, en lugar de `UserForm1`, `UserForm2`, `ComboBox1`, `TextBox1`, etc, puedes usar `frmEntradas`, `frmSalidas`, `cboIdProducto`, `txtNombreProducto`, etc.

### El Error

En cuanto al error, en la imagen se puede ver que estas trabajando en un formulario llamado "`UserForm21`", en el código se ve que intentas obtener el valor de campos como `UserFomr3.ComboBox1`, `Userform3.TextBox1` y ponerlo en celdas.

El problema es que `UserForm3` no existe en tu proyecto, por eso da el error.

Si ese código esta dentro del mismo formulario que contiene los datos capturados (es lo regular), no necesitas poner `UserForm1.ComboBox1`, etc, puedes usar `Me.ComboBox1`, etc.

Pero lo ideal seria que como dije antes, uses nombres descriptivos y puedas poner `Me.cboIdProducto.text` o `Me.txtNombreProducto.text`, `Me.txtCantidadSalida.value`, etc.

Comment: Compañero muchas gracias por su aporte, será que se lo podría enviar a un correo para que me ayudes mirándolo por favor

Comment: La solución esta en mi respuesta, el problema es que intentas acceder a un `UserForm` que no existe `UserFomr3.ComboBox1`, solo tienes que hacer referencia al `UserForm` correcto o usar `Me.ComboBox1.text`